# docker-compose nginx certbot not found certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, lets-encrypt, certbot

I want to create a docker-compose with several services and in it I want to generate a certificate for my domain name with Certbot/LetsEncryt. But when I run it, I always get an error saying it can't find a certificate! While normally I do everything necessary to generate it.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy-nginx:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    depends_on:
      - nestjs
    restart: unless-stopped

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    depends_on:
      - proxy-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot --email emain@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging 0 --force-renewal -d www.mydomaine -d mydomaine

  nestjs:
    build:
      context: ./BACKEND
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Here is the result :

````bash
cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomaine/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomaine/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

```


In my nginx.conf file
I have 1 proxy server and 1 server for the front-end and back-end of my application. But the problem is nginx can't find the certificate. I don't know why.
normally the certificate is generated in the folder /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomaine.be/ but it's not the case.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I use it and it works.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  node:
    container_name: node-server
    build: .
    environment: # process.env.
      NODE_ENV: production
    networks:
      - app-network
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.23.3'
    container_name: nginx-server
    depends_on:
      - node
    volumes:
      - './volumes/nginx/production/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
      - './volumes/nginx/production/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
      - './volumes/certbot/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
      - './volumes/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot'
    networks:
      - app-network 
    ports:
      - '80:80' # To access nginx from outside
      - '443:443' # To access nginx from outside
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Docker run certbot

```
docker run --rm --name temp_certbot \
    -v /home/app-folder/volumes/certbot/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
    -v /home/app-folder/volumes/certbot/www:/tmp/letsencrypt \
    -v /home/app-folder/volumes/certbot/log:/var/log \
    certbot/certbot:v1.8.0 \
    certonly --webroot --agree-tos --renew-by-default \
    --preferred-challenges http-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
    --text --email info@domain.com \
    -w /tmp/letsencrypt -d domain.com
```

Comment: perhaps could you provide a full docker-compose.yml template to be more precise ?

Comment: how are you running the certbot container when non exist in your docker-compose file ?

Comment: @Macdonald I already wrote this. You can see it under "Docker run certbot". A one-time run is enough to generate the certificate. No need to be dependent.